# react-native-youtube-iframe ref returning undefined

Tags: react-native

I'm building a `TypeScript` React Native mobile app. I'm using a [YouTube iframe package](https://lonelycpp.github.io/react-native-youtube-iframe/component-ref-methods) and I have built some custom controller elements to control it with the functions of the YouTube iframe ref object. But the ref of the object always returns undefined value. Need help

`Code:`

```
import React, { MutableRefObject, ReactNode } from "react";

import YoutubeIframe, { PLAYER_STATES, YoutubeIframeRef } from "react-native-youtube-iframe";



export default class YouTubeVideoPlayer extends React.Component<Props, State> {

  private player?: MutableRefObject<YoutubeIframeRef | null> = undefined;

  render(): ReactNode {

    return <>
      <YoutubeIframe
        videoId={this.props.id}
        ref={this.player}            // Returning undefined
        play={false}
        ...
      />
    </>;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

declare with createRef if you use Class component

```
player = React.createRef()
```

or using useRef if you use function component

```
const player  = React.useRef()
```

you can view [example](https://lonelycpp.github.io/react-native-youtube-iframe/component-ref-methods)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a Class Component, you need to set the ref manually instead of passing it as a prop:

```js
    return <>
      <YoutubeIframe
        videoId={this.props.id}
        ref={ref => { this.player = ref}}            
        play={false}
        ...
      />
    </>;
```

Or what you need to do is convert the component to a function component and use `useRef`

**EXAMPLE**

```js
 const YouTubeVideoPlayer = ({ id }) => {

  // Note that whenever you need to use the ref you need to access 
  // player.current?.whatever
  const player = useRef<YoutubeIframeRef | null>(null);

    return (
      <>
      <YoutubeIframe
        videoId={id}
        ref={player}           
        play={false}
        ...
      />
    </>;
  )
}
```